# Should the [sqlanywhere] tag be [sql-anywhere], like [sql-server]

Tags: discussion, status-completed, tags, synonym-request

Sybase iAnywhere's "SQL Anywhere" product contains a space in its name, just like Microsoft's "SQL Server" contains a space. Yet Microsoft's Stack Overflow tag ([sql-server](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/sql-server)) has a dash, but Sybase's  ([sqlanywhere](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/sqlanywhere))does not.

In the least, [sql-anywhere](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/sql-anywhere) should be a synonym (searching for "[sql-anywhere](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/sql-anywhere)" returns no results).

Comment: I think, both sqlanywhere and sql-anywhere should be synonyms. Tag sql-anywhere is a lot better to comprehend.